# OpenLDAP vs Active Directory authentication mechanisms

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am able to log in to an Active Directory using the `userPrincipalName` attribute of a `user` objectClass; (e.g. `foo@mydomain.com`)

I have also set up an `OpenLDAP` server instance to which I can **only** authenticate using the `dn`, e.g.

`"cn=somecn,cn=anothercn,ou=someou,dc=mydomain,dc=com"`

How is it possible to authenticate to `OpenLDAP` using another field, e.g. the `mail` attribute of the `inetOrgPerson` for example?

What is more, **even** if such thing **were** possible, how would anyone ensure uniqueness of the field? (a functionality I assume is offered by AD in terms of the `userPrincipalName` field)

Comment: Are you writing an application of some sort that authenticates users against LDAP, or trying to configure a particular OS to allow logins using the `mail` attribute? If so, what OS exactly? (assumedly something *nix-ish)

Comment: It is an application that will auth users against the ldap but I was wondering whether that application is able to perform login directly via another unique kind of attribute (other than that I think it is feasible for the app to make us of ldapsearch of some kind to map e.g. mails to DNs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenLDAP supports two authentication methods (`simple` and `SASL`), while `SASL` is the default method for ldap-utils like `ldapsearch`.

When you are authenticating using the DN, you do a so called "simple bind".

## simple bind

The `simple` method has three modes of operation:

- anonymous
- unauthenticated
- user/password authenticated

For example:

```
# ldapwhoami -x
anonymous
```

or:

```
# ldapwhoami -x -D uid=rda,ou=people,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch -w secret1234
dn:uid=rda,ou=people,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch
```

## SASL

OpenLDAP clients and servers are capable of authenticating via the Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL) framework, which is detailed in [RFC4422](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4422.txt). SASL supports several authentication mechanisms. The most common mechanisms with OpenLDAP are `EXTERNAL` and `GSSAPI`.

The **EXTERNAL** mechanism makes use of an authentication performed by a lower-level protocol: usually TLS or Unix IPC. For example using Unix IPC as user root:

```
# ldapwhoami -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi://
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn:gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
```

The authenitcated user is mapped to a DN in the tree `cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth`.

The **GSSAPI** mechanism usually means Kerveros 5. If you have a Kerberos 5 infrastructure deployed you can use Kerberos Principals for authentication.

First authenticate against the KDC and get a TGT:

```
# kinit rda
Password for rda@PHYS.ETHZ.CH: secret1234
```

Then you can use GSSAPI for authentication against OpenLDAP:

```
# ldapwhoami
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: rda@PHYS.ETHZ.CH
SASL SSF: 56
SASL data security layer installed.
dn:uid=rda,cn=gssapi,cn=auth
```

The principal `rda@PHYS.ETHZ.CH` is mapped to a DN in the tree `cn=gssapi,cn=auth`.

Now you can map that authenticated DN to an actual DN in the database using a regular expression with the `olcAuthzRegexp` configuration in `cn=config`:

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcAuthzRegexp: {0}uid=([^,/]*),cn=phys.ethz.ch,cn=gssapi,cn=auth uid=$1,ou=people,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch
...
```

This `olcAuthzRegexp` line maps any user principal in the realm `PHYS.ETHZ.CH` to a corresponding `posixAccount` entry under `ou=people,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch` which has the same username in the `uid` attribute.

For example with the following posix entry

```
# ldapsearch uid=rda
dn: uid=rda,ou=people,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: krbPrincipalAux
objectClass: krbTicketPolicyAux
uid: rda
krbPrincipalName: rda@PHYS.ETHZ.CH
...
```

`ldapwhoami` will show:

```
# ldapwhoami
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: rda@PHYS.ETHZ.CH
SASL SSF: 56
SASL data security layer installed.
dn:uid=rda,ou=people,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch
```

The mapping using `olcAuthzRegexp` must match a unique entry in the DIT. This is to be ensured by the administrator or the managing software.

Comment: You could possible use the `rwm` module to map from an email address to a DN, but I have never tried that. See `man 5 slapo-rwm`.

Comment: many thanx for this well elaborated solution;